# blender import/export script

Tags: python, import, export, blender

I should create a python script for Blender that imports obj and exports obj removing all texture sections.
I never used blender, is there a good tutorial for scratch the surface and achieve this simple task?

thank you

Answer (score 5):

The [blender python api](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/) website includes several tutorials to learn using python in blender. You can find details of the obj [importer](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.import_scene.html#bpy.ops.import_scene.obj) and [exporter](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.obj) options. The obj import/export is handled by a python addon that is [included with blender](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_scene_obj/).

You could start with something as simple as -

```
import bpy,os
for f in os.listdir('/path/to/use'):
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=f)
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=f,use_materials=False)
```

If you need more help, blender has it's own [SE site](http://blender.stackexchange.com) that is better for blender specific scripting.