# Applying a Python script to a large amount of .obj files in Blender

Tags: python, cmd, scripting, automation, blender

I want to, perhaps using the command line, run Blender in background mode and have it process a large number of individual .obj files. "Process" means applying a few commands to the single mesh contained within each .obj file, and then export each modified mesh as a new .obj file in a new dir. ***TLDR:*** I've made a script, but the problem I'm having is understanding how I would run the script upon a large number of .obj files.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import os
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)

bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(100, 100, 100))

bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath="C:\\output", check_existing=True)
```

This seems like a simple problem, but no amount of googling has helped. Documentations says I can execute the following in cmd, but I don't understand how I would translate it to this situation.

```
blender myscene.blend --background --python myscript.py
```

Remember, I'm working with a ton of .obj files, no .blend files.

Comment: You want to use a loop that will perform the same thing for each file. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939643/2684771) is an example of importing and exporting multiple objs - add your steps into the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the command line using say a for loop in Windows cmd.exe

```
for %%F IN (file1.blend,flie2.blend,file3.blend) DO (blender %%F --background --python myscript.py)
```

Or under unix (bash/sh)

```
for file in *.blend; do blender "$file" --background --python myscript.py; done
```

Or have I not understood your question.  This answer seems to simple.

Comment: Using the first one, what could I replace the list of .blend files with? I have a large directory of .obj files, not a small list .blend files. How would blender know to import those from cmd? Wrap the commands in an import script?