# Is it possible to import 2 files with a single code? or how to import all the files from a single directory?

Tags: import, blender, stl-format

It is possible to choose the exact file within a directory where there are several files?
Basically, I want to see the inside of a directory and then import a file (* .stl)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to get a list of files matching a pattern.

```
import glob
stl_files = glob.glob('*.stl')
```

If you can expect more than one stl file in a directory you can loop through the file list and import each file, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939643/2684771).