# convert .3ds file to .obj /collada / gltf using npm package / python script

Tags: python, node.js, npm, cesiumjs, 3ds

I have some .3ds format files ,I want to convert it to gltf format.

Is there any package to convert it direct to .gltf format or to collada/.obj format.
As for collada/.obj to gltf ,there are npm package available.

I need some npm package or python script (not software - have already tried Spin3DMesh ,It is able to convert but I need some npm package or python script).

packages already tried are : parse-3ds ,3dstojs but they are not giving output as Spin3DMesh.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, current versions of Blender (2.80+) don't support `.3ds`, but older versions (`2.79`) do. So you might be able to do a Python script (see [blender import/export script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926423/blender-import-export-script)) that imports the 3DS file into Blender and exports to something else.

> NOTE: A `.3ds` file is meant to be read by 3D Studio Max. Support in other software — if it exists at all — will be very incomplete. If there is any possible way to get a different format, designed for support in multiple programs, I would try to do so. OBJ, FBX, and glTF are all much more broadly compatible formats.